# Fitting elements into a grid in a responsive way

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid-layout

Consider a `<div>` element that contains `<button>` elements:

```
<div id="box">
    <button class="button">1</button>
    <button class="button">2</button>
    <button class="button">3</button>
    ...
</div>
```

I want to fit these elements into a grid pattern, so that

1. buttons are of equal dimensions and have a fixed minimum width,
2. a maximal amount of buttons is stacked on each row,
3. button width is adjusted so that each row is filled completely,
4. and this behavior persists when `#box` is resized.

Is there a way to do so using native HTML/CSS features (without using JavaScript)? I tried using the new CSS **Flexbox** layout:

```
#box {
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.button {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

But this doesn't work..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS flex for this, as you suspected.

`flex-wrap` is what you were missing, as well as using percentages for responsiveness.

```css
#box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#box > * {
  flex: 1 0 100px; /* each button should be at least 100px wide */
}
```

```html
<div id='box'>
  <button class='button'>1</button>
  <button class='button'>2</button>
  <button class='button'>3</button>
  <button class='button'>4</button>
  <button class='button'>5</button>
  <button class='button'>6</button>
  <button class='button'>7</button>
  <button class='button'>8</button>
  <button class='button'>9</button>
  <button class='button'>10</button>
  <button class='button'>11</button>
  <button class='button'>12</button>
  <button class='button'>13</button>
  <button class='button'>14</button>
  <button class='button'>15</button>
  <button class='button'>16</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is much simpler than I expected! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use CSS grid layout.
I prefer it over flexbox.

```
<div id='grid'>
      <button class='button'>1</button>
      <button class='button'>2</button>
      <button class='button'>3</button>
      <button class='button'>4</button>
      <button class='button'>5</button>
      <button class='button'>6</button>
      <button class='button'>7</button>
      <button class='button'>8</button>
      <button class='button'>9</button>
      <button class='button'>10</button>
      <button class='button'>11</button>
      <button class='button'>12</button>
      <button class='button'>13</button>
      <button class='button'>14</button>
      <button class='button'>15</button>
      <button class='button'>16</button>
</div>

<style>
  #grid {
    display: grid;
    grid: 50px / auto-flow;
  }
</style>
```

Here is the codepen.

https://codepen.io/kenanbalija/pen/bYYarj

Comment: @NaïmFavier How is it not working, did you check the **codepen**? 
It satisfies all of the following:
1) buttons are of equal dimensions and have a fixed minimum width 
2) a maximal amount of buttons is stacked on each row 
3) button width is adjusted so that each row is filled completely,
4) and this behavior persists when #box is resized.
And its a **grid** layout like you asked using css Grids!

Comment: The buttons have no minimum width in this example. Adding it manually to the CSS doesn't work either.